# SQL two different tables in combobox and textfield from same database in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, netbeans

I have created a MySQL database in Netbeans with two tables (varchar and integer), both connected on the same database, and three GUI elements jcombobox, jtextfield, jbutton and jlist. How is it possible, when connecting varchar table to jcombobox, to make jtextfield to remember numerical that is relative to varchar table?

> (for example, varchar that is displayed in combobox has columns like
>   computer,laptop, console and integer has columns 500 (computer),
>   450(laptop) and 250(console))

and so user can put numerical values in jtextfiled

> (500 , 450 and 250 are not displayed but remembered when user selects
>   one item from combobox)

and after user clicks on button, the value that user has put in jtextfield are being multiplied to numbers in integer table

> (whatever user chooses in jcombobox)

and then final result is shown in jlist (or is jtable is better for such data representation?) where is shown choosen item, lets say it was laptop with calculated numbers, for example 4050.

Is it possible, and how, to make those tables to be assigned to different GUI elements and then get together again?

Thank you, and sorry for confusing English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (500 , 450 and 250 are not displayed but remembered when user selects one item from combobox)

Then you need to store an Object in the combo box that contains two properties:

1. the description
2. the number

Then you render the combo box to display the description, but then for later processing you can access the number for calculations.

For an example of this approach check out [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/).

> and so user can put numerical values in jtextfiled

Maybe you should use a `JSpinner` so you get automatic editing to make sure only numeric values are entered.

Comment: Thank you, I will do changes and will let know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use onFocus event on the jCombobox which then pass the value as a SQL query and fetch the corresponding details and then show that in jTable.If you have  larger number of values then I will say use Jtable as for better representation.
Moreover, please add some more details to your question.

Comment: Thank you! Which details are you interested in, I thought that there was already everything what is needed?